# jquery function setInterval

Tags: jquery, function, setinterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setInterval(swapImages(),1000);

    function swapImages(){

        var active = $('.active'); 
        var next = ($('.active').next().length > 0) ? $('.active').next() : $('#siteNewsHead img:first');

        active.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
    }
});
```

I have 13 images contained in a div. The first one has a class called active, which means it is displayed.

The swap images function selects the active image and hides it, and makes the next image active.

However, when the page loads, the function only works correctly once, rather than looping.

Any ideas?

Comment: `setInterval` is not a jQuery function.  It is a builtin JavaScript function.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This is because you are executing the function not referencing it. You should do:

```
  setInterval(swapImages,1000);
```

Answer (score 15):

Don't pass the result of `swapImages` to `setInterval` by invoking it. Just pass the function, like this:

```
setInterval(swapImages, 1000);
```

Comment: Right answer just one minute late. Thought you deserved an upvote.

Answer (score 4):

// simple example using the concept of setInterval

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var g = $('.jumping');
function blink(){
  g.animate({ 'left':'50px' 
  }).animate({
     'left':'20px'
        },1000)
}
setInterval(blink,1500);
});
```

Comment: JUST RECYCLE THE FUNCTION...THAT'S ALL

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need

```
setInterval(function() { alert("Haha"); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    setTimeout("swapImages()",1000);

    function swapImages(){

        var active = $('.active'); 
        var next = ($('.active').next().length > 0) ? $('.active').next() : $('#siteNewsHead img:first');

        active.removeClass('active');
        next.addClass('active');
        setTimeout("swapImages()",1000);
}
```

});

Comment: No, becuase like this you call the function. you need to pass a reference to it: parenthesis are not needed

Comment: Yeah, I confused it with setTimeout function. Just edited the post

Comment: Passing the code s you do is a bad practice because the code is evalued

Comment: You're thinking of `setTimeout`, not `setInterval`, which will keep executing the code at regular intervals own its own.

Answer (score -1):

try this declare the function outside the ready event.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){    
       setInterval(swapImages(),1000); 
    });


    function swapImages(){

    var active = $('.active'); 
    var next = ($('.active').next().length > 0) ? $('.active').next() :         $('#siteNewsHead img:first');
    active.removeClass('active');
    next.addClass('active');
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem. The function will still execute once, when the DOM's ready event fires and not every 1000 ms from that point on.